# what is the IDE for using SPECMAN

Tags: ide, specman

I have been searching for what IDE to use in order to start studying SPECAMAN.

I would like to know what is the IDE for e/specman and where I can download it ?

Also if there is a good tutoriaal for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a plugin for eclipse which costs money.  http://www.dvteclipse.com/  I've never tried it.

Most people at my work use VIM or emacs to edit e-files.  I use [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).

[Here's a crash-course on Specman.](http://www.asic-world.com/specman/specman_one_day1.html)

Comment: I've been using DVT for a few years now and it's great!